# How do I remove a c++ project's source code from a locally cloned Git repository without affecting the remote repository?

Tags: git

On a lab computer I have a local Git repository of a c++ project that I cloned from a remote repository.  I compiled the code into an executable, and now I want to remove just the source code (leaving data files, configuration files, executables, etc.) on this lab computer, because there are people from other companies in this lab on this computer sometimes that I don't want to see the source code.

Is there a slick way to erase the source code locally while keeping a Git relationship to the remote repository in case I want to push some changes (such as configuration files we changed in the lab) back to the remote repository?

Maybe I could make a branch that doesn't contain the source code?  Or keep source code in a separate repository from data and configuration files?

Comment: If you don't trust the local machine, don't use it in the first place. But I would hope that you've cloned to a personal directory? Isn't the machine set up to prevent other users from accessing your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if the source code is in your git where ever you download the project with git all the files will there no mater what you do. I don't know why you don't want to delete the full project from an unsafe device. Well there are some ways from me is that

1. Use your home pc and compile the project there and just update all the files without the code on the git now where ever you use the git you will get all the files without the source codes.

and always remember git is for version control so what ever you do locally or remotely all records will there and any time you can get the records and go back to your old versions that's why git is used. So as you are searching to hide your codes on git that are recorded in your lab others will searching how to get git recorded files.

Now it's up to you what purpose you are using the git.

Answer (score -1):

create a `.gitignore` and add those files/dirs

delete folders from the local drive you don't want and then `git clean -f`

that should remove those deleted files from the index and maintain the git repo and the remote configuration

Comment: Git's ignore system has no effect on tracked files